# Swapping structures

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
int Employee_id;
char Employee_Name[50];
float Employee_salary;

} employee;

void swap(employee *a,employee *b);

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int n;
    int iter,iter2,iter3,iter4;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    employee *start = (employee *)malloc(n*sizeof(employee));

    employee temp;

    for (iter = 0; iter < n;iter++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&((*(start+iter)).Employee_id));
            scanf("%s",(*(start+iter)).Employee_Name);
            scanf("%f",&((*(start+iter)).Employee_salary));

        }


    //USING BUBBLE SORT TO SORT ON BASIS OF IDS
    for (iter2 = 1; iter2 <=n; iter2++)
    {
        for (iter3 = 0; iter3 <n-iter2 ; iter3++)
        {
            if ((start[iter3]).Employee_id > (start[iter3+1]).Employee_id)
            {
                swap(&start[iter3+1],&start[iter3]);
            }
        }
    }

    //PRINTING
    for (iter4 = 0; iter4 < n; iter4++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",(*(start+iter4)).Employee_id);
        printf("%s\n",(*(start+iter4)).Employee_Name);
        printf("%f\n",(*(start+iter4)).Employee_salary);
        printf("\n");

    }
    free(start);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}





void swap(employee  *a,employee *b)
{
employee temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}
```

I am trying to swap structures on the basis of employee id,I get no errors on compilation.But when I try to swap structures the program terminates abruptly. The same swap works well for ints and other basic types but not for structs.Thanks for help.

Comment: You should `malloc` after you read `n`.

Comment: still the same thing happens,the problem is with swap,If i comment it out everything works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` loop for sorting.

```
for (iter2 = 0; iter2 <n; iter2++)
{
    for (iter3 = 0; iter3 <n-iter2 ; iter3++) //LINE A
    {
        if ((start[iter3]).Employee_id > (start[iter3+1]).Employee_id)
        {
            swap(&start[iter3+1],&start[iter3]);
        }
    }
}
```

At LINE A, when `iter2` is 0, then inner loop will from 0 to n-1. When, `iter3` is `n-1`, you are accessing an item at `n` which will lead to undefined behaviour (out of bound index).

So, change your code as follows:

```
for (iter2 = 0; iter2 <n; iter2++)
{
    for (iter3 = 0; iter3 <n - 1 -iter2 ; iter3++)
    {
        if ((start[iter3]).Employee_id > (start[iter3+1]).Employee_id)
        {
            swap(&start[iter3+1],&start[iter3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Please make sure that at any iteration of the loop, there should be not out of bound access.

Comment: thank u,so there is no problem in swapping,it works the same way as basic types?

Comment: For your structure, it works same way. It is just swapping bit by bit.

Comment: Hence preserving string values.

Comment: also should I only swap pointers to structures rather than swapping the structures themselves?

Comment: also the way you suggested modifying loops will not allow me to check the last value while sorting,I have modified the code so I stay in bounds and also check all elements,please see if its correct now

Comment: @dbasic: For structures larger then pointers swapping pointer values would be the preferable approach, yes.

Comment: @user2688772: We would need an array of pointers to the structure to just swap pointers (which would possibly complicate memory allocation)...

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to this line, where `n` is being used without initialization.

```
employee *start = malloc(n*sizeof(employee));
```

To solve this, you need to swap these two lines:

```
employee *start = malloc(n*sizeof(employee));
scanf("%d",&n);
```

---

In addition, you need to add explicit type casting here, change this line to:

```
employee *start = (employee *)malloc(n*sizeof(employee));
```

---

**Edit**: `swap()` is no problem. See the following test:

```
employee a, b;
a.Employee_id = 1;
a.Employee_Name[0] = 'a';
a.Employee_salary = 10.0;
b.Employee_id = 2;
b.Employee_Name[0] = 'b';
b.Employee_salary = 20.0;
swap(&a, &b);
```

After this, `a.Employee_id=2` and `b.Employee_id=1`, etc.

Comment: the main problem is with swap

Comment: Actually, in C the cast is not needed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia So are all explicit type casting not needed in C?

Comment: @herehuyongtao: no, it's just the cast from `void *` to any pointer type that can be carried out implicitly (probably also some other casts are allowed to be implicit, but this is the one about which C programmers tend to be picky about).

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
swap(&start[iter3+1], ...
```

accesses the array `start` out of bounds for `iter3==n`  (`iter2 == 0`).

So the program invokes undefined behaviuor.